# Input sanitization - Date value

Tags: oracle, date, plsql

Not able to convert input parameter to date. Can anyone please check and point out what is the issue here.

```
DECLARE
  v_str VARCHAR2(50):='14-OCT-2023';
  v_date DATE;
BEGIN
  v_date:=TO_DATE(DBMS_ASSERT.ENQUOTE_NAME(v_str),'DD-MON-YYYY');
END;
/

ERROR:
ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected.
ORA-06512: at line 5
```

Answer (score 4):

> Can anyone please check and point out what is the issue here.

The issue is that `DBMS_ASSERT.ENQUOTE_NAME(v_str)` gives `"14-OCT-2023"` which does not match the format model `DD-MON-YYYY` as it is surrounded by quotes. Don't try to enquote the value as either a name or a literal.

Just use `TO_DATE` and either catch the exception if it is not valid:

```sql
DECLARE
  v_str VARCHAR2(50):='14-OCT-2023';
  v_date DATE;
BEGIN
  BEGIN
    v_date:=TO_DATE(v_str,'DD-MON-YYYY');
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SQLERRM);
  END;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_date);
END;
/
```

or, from Oracle 12, use `DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR`:

```sql
DECLARE
  v_str VARCHAR2(50):='14-OCT-2023';
  v_date DATE;
BEGIN
  v_date:=TO_DATE(v_str DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR,'DD-MON-YYYY');
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_date);
END;
/
```

Both of which output (assuming that the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` is `YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS`):

> ```
> 2023-10-14 00:00:00
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/D5A0vjVh)

Answer (score 1):

From my point of view, when dealing with dates then use proper datatype: `date`. Why would you want to use strings (`varchar2`) and then worry about what you passed? Pass date in the first place!

---

As error you got: function you used encloses value into double quotes:

```
SQL> SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
SQL> DECLARE
  2    v_str VARCHAR2(50):='14-OCT-2023';
  3    v_date DATE;
  4  BEGIN
  5    dbms_output.put_line(DBMS_ASSERT.ENQUOTE_NAME(v_str));
  6  END;
  7  /
"14-OCT-2023"       --> this is what ENQUOTE_NAME returns

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

so - if you pass it to `to_date`, it'll fail as `"14-OCT-2023"` isn't valid value:

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2    v_str VARCHAR2(50):='14-OCT-2023';
  3    v_date DATE;
  4  BEGIN
  5    v_date: = TO_DATE(DBMS_ASSERT.ENQUOTE_NAME(v_str), 'DD-MON-YYYY');
  6  END;
  7  /
  v_date: = TO_DATE(DBMS_ASSERT.ENQUOTE_NAME(v_str), 'DD-MON-YYYY');
        *
ERROR at line 5:
ORA-06550: line 5, column 9:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol " " when expecting one of the following:
:= . ( @ % ;


SQL>
```

Comment: I have tried DBMS_ASSERT.ENQUOTE_LITERAL also. It gives same error. So, not sure why it is happening

Comment: Regarding why I am taking IN param as VARCHAR2 because it is coming from front-end and I don't want to break anything

Comment: It doesn't matter what you *enquote* - you'll get **double quotes** around it, and it just won't work. Maybe you should just accept what you get, and - at the beginning of your procedure - try to transform it into a valid DATE datatype value. If it goes well, fine - value was OK. If not, reject it.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you're trying to assert that the date-as-a-string input meets the requirements of an identifier name, which of course it doesn't.

In this instance, there is no need to assert the input, since your variable is going to be used inside the `to_date()` function, and if the string doesn't match the specified format, the function will return an error.

Better still would be to pass the date in as a date rather than a string. Also, as an aside - if you are going to use words in your date-as-a-string input, don't forget to add in the relevant nls_date_language parameter, e.g. `to_date(v_str, 'dd-MON-yyyy', 'nls_date_language=english')`